# Directory "Bookmarking" in Linux

Tags: linux

Aside from aliasing and links, is there an easy way in Linux to tag commonly used directories and to navigate to a commonly used directory from the terminal.

To be clear the disadvantages I see with alternative approaches, and why I want a bookmark/favorites like system:
`alias`
Cons:
Too specific (every new favorite requires a new `alias`...although you could in theory make an alias that `echo` append your dir as a new `alias`, which would be sort of clever). Can't nest favorites in folders (can't think of a simple solution to this outside of heavy config scripting).

`links`
Cons:
Clutter directory make `ls` a headache.

`pushd`/`popd`
Cons:
Non-permanent (without shell config file scripting), can't nest favorites in directories, etc.

Granted I have multiple ideas for making my own non-standard solution, but before I have at it I wanted to get some perspective on what's out there and if there is nothing, what is a recommended approach.

Does anyone know of such a favorites/bookmark-like terminal solution?

Comment: Many shells also have a `$CDPATH`; this could be combined with one or more of the other solutions, for example to reduce the clutter from links. by hiding them in a dot-directory and putting that in `$CDPATH`.

Comment: `set` doesn't do what you think it does.  (Try `echo $1` in the shell where you did that.)  It's just `CDPATH=whatever`.

Comment: How to use that var, though? I thought it might allow me to say `cd tools` if I had a folder named `~/<dir>/<dir>/tools/`, but no luck.

Comment: What exactly did you set `CDPATH` to, for that?  (Beware that `~` is not always expanded in such cases; you may want to use `$HOME` instead.)

Comment: Pretty much identical to the example above... tried it with `$HOME` and it still didn't work.  e.g. COMMAND 1: `CDPATH=$HOME/<dir>/<dir>/tools` COMMAND 2:`echo $CDPATH` (displays full verbose path correctly) COMMAND 3:`cd tools` (yields `bash: cd: tools: No such file or directory`)

Comment: `CDPATH` works like `PATH`; if you have `CDPATH=$HOME/dir1/dir2` then `cd tools` will look for `$HOME/dir1/dir2/tools`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, got it... working now.  Cool feature.  Does not work in `tcsh`, but still neat.  What does it do when there's a conflict (e.g. if two directories have a `tools` subdirectory)?

Comment: The first one found wins, just as with `PATH` search.

Comment: Cool, thanks for all the info.  If I do go the custom solutions route, this would be very helpful... or maybe even as an alternative, as it has some advantages on the above options. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add my 2 cents.

[**qwe**](https://github.com/olafurw/olafurw-home/blob/master/tools/qwe.sh)

```
Usage:
qwe name : Traverse to directory tagged name
qwe -h : Help
qwe -l : List of saved tag
qwe -a name : Add a tag called name with the current folder"
qwe -d name : Remove a tag called name
qwe -p name : Print the directory tagged with name
```

To install, just store the script somewhere and source it in your `.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

cdargs is the best tool for bookmarking a directory : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uWB2FIQlzZg

Comment: And is available from `cdargs` package

Answer (score 2):

There is also **[bashmarks](http://www.huyng.com/projects/bashmarks/)** project (for bash shell), which uses one-letter commands for managing directory bookmarks:

```
s <bookmark_name> - Saves the current directory as "bookmark_name"
g <bookmark_name> - Goes (cd) to the directory associated with "bookmark_name"
p <bookmark_name> - Prints the directory associated with "bookmark_name"
d <bookmark_name> - Deletes the bookmark
l                 - Lists all available bookmarks
```

Answer (score 1):

I use one-letter variables for temporal bookmarking, and properly named symlinks for permanent storage.

Answer (score 0):

[Apparix](http://micans.org/apparix) is a pure command-line implementation (that is, not menu-driven) for both bash and zsh of bookmarks. It is possible to jump to subdirectories of the bookmarks and tab-complete on those subdirectories. This is what gives it the most oomph.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not terminal, but mc :)
https://midnight-commander.org/
feature > The Directory Hotlist

I use it and love it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).